# The type of array in the line

Tags: c

I am new to programming, and the following line confused me:

> switch_block_conn[from_side][to_side][from_track].nelem = 0

Is this line actually describing an array? What is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the syntax in the given code sample, assuming it is valid code, it is implied that:

- `switch_block_conn` is a 3-d array. You can infer this from the 3 array index operations.
- The individual elements in `switch_block_conn` are structs. You can infer this from the `.` operator used.
- Those structs have (among potentially other members), an `nelem` member. You can infer this from the name given after the `.`.
- The `nelem` member is a numeric or pointer type (specific size and type unknown from this sample). You can infer this from the assignment of 0 to that member.

Note that most of these conclusions can be drawn only in C and not C++ due to operator overloading in C++.